# Can I use semi-graphics to display badges in terminal?

Tags: unicode, terminal, badge

I want to display some single-line badges (with rounded corners) in terminal but I am not aware of any box characters to use for start and end of labels. Are there any?
The label text would be normal text on coloured background, the only issue is that i need some elements to make it more visually appealing.

Comment: Is this what you mean? `❲❳⟬⟭⦗⦘〔〕〘〙﹝﹞` If not, edit the question and attach an image.

Comment: I need something resembling a filled semicircle in order to compose a badge-looking construct. Anything that is not fully filed on right or left side would not helping on creating the object.

Comment: If you mean something the full size of the character cell (like the block characters ░▒▓█▓▒░), only shaped like a left half circle or right half circle ◖◗, then you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Not semicircles, but there will be more box-type graphics characters soon. Unicode 13.0, scheduled for March 2020*, will have a new block: "Symbols for Legacy Computing". This was designed for emulation of various 1970s and '80s computers, but some of the characters could also be useful for more modern purposes. [This PDF](https://www.unicode.org/L2/L2019/19025-terminals-prop.pdf) has the code chart.

*Of course, that's just when the codepoints become official, you will still need to find a font that has the characters.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is not possible as I failed to find any Unicode characters that do that.

The only one closer to enabling building a badge-like construct is `U+258C` also known as **left half block**: `▌`.

Its sibling is `U+2590`.

Obviously that it does not have rounded corners so this would not help a lot visually.